# How to make "events" using "eventnews" extension

Tags: events, typo3, tx-news

I am using this extension with TYPO3 v10 https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/eventnews/ I created a news content and marked it as **"Is event"** set the dates, simple organizer name and location.

But this is what I am seeing on the frontend. it doesn't look like an event to me but similar to the news. Can anybody direct me in a way how can I create an "event"?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically this is what you get, as the eventnews extension does simply that: It allows news entries to be created as "events" (some additional fields). So at first you get the same views you also have with news, but some additional fields.

One additional new view you can include in your page is the "month view".

Refer to the [documentation of eventnews](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/eventnews/stable/UsersManual/Index.html).

To add a **Month View**, you could do that by simply adding a plugin to your content:

[image]

All other things you might need are already there in news (filtering, searching, etc), and customization can be done using templates.

If you need further "event-like" features (like registration, recurring events etc), this might not be the right extension. Try for example [EXT:cal](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/cal/) or [EXT:seminars](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/seminars/).

Comment: Yes that i saw, but i was unable to determine how to add this additional view. i dont see it in templates section, so that i can include it on my page.

Comment: alright i was able to get the calendar now, i copied the "Month.html" from this path `"public\typo3conf\ext\eventnews\Resources\Private\Templates\News\Month.html"` ----> To this path: `"public\typo3conf\ext\news\Resources\Private\Templates\News"` - Without this i was getting this error: `"Sorry, the requested view was not found. The technical reason is: No template was found. View could not be resolved for action "month" in class "GeorgRinger\News\Controller\NewsController"."`